# impl push(self , item : T) for a struct with 2 Vecs<T>

Tags: rust, traits, borrowing

I've been trying to impl the push for this struct:

```rust
struct StackMin<T: std::cmp::Ord>
{
    stack : Vec<T>,
    min : Vec<T>
}
```

like this:

```rust
fn push(&mut self, item: T) {
    let l = self.stack.len();
    let x: T;
    match l {
        0 => println!("There is nothing in the stack."),
        n => {
            if item <= self.stack[l - 1] {
                self.stack.push(item); //item moved here
                self.min.push(item); // so I can't use it again here
            } else {
                self.stack.push(item);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is item moves with the first `Vec<T>::push` so I can't use it immediately at the second call of push(). I thought about making a variable `let a = &item` and use it in the second call, but push requires "T" and not "&T".

Also, if I try to do `a=self.stack[l-1]`, it's an error because the `T` type doesn't have the `Copy`/`Clone` traits.

LATER EDIT: I also need to print the last value from the min Vector. But it doesn't have the std::fmt::Display , and I don't think it can be impl!? Any ideas?

How would you approach this?

Comment: Assuming that you do need the two vectors of T, there's not much you can do here. A thing can't be in two places at the same time. Either have one (or both) of the vectors store `&T` (at this point you'll have to deal with lifetimes) or additionally constrain T to Clone or Copy.

Comment: why not constrain to `Clone`?

Comment: Buy how do I proceed to create the Clone/Copy traits for the <T> type?

Comment: Just `<T: std::cmp::Ord + Clone>`?

Comment: I would want to avoid that. The challenge specifically mentions the type T: std::cmp::Ord

Comment: It is simply impossible to implement given these constraints, which suggests this is an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/). Back up a bit: what are you trying to make?

Comment: @trentcl I'm trying to solve the min stack problem using struct StackMin<T: std::cmp::Ord> struct restriction.

Comment: What's "the" min stack problem? You mean [this](https://leetcode.com/problems/min-stack/)? But that's not generic...

Comment: @trentcl I know it's not generic, but it was a challenge to do it with generics

Comment: Do they have to both be `Vec<T>`? The `min` vec could be `Vec<usize>` indexing the other...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you can change the inner values of the struct `StackMin`, but not the trait requirements, you could do something like this:

```
struct MinStack<T: std::cmp::Ord> {
    // T is the data you want to store
    // and usize points to the smallest T
    inner: Vec<(T, usize)>
}

impl<T: std::cmp::Ord> MinStack<T> {
    fn push(&mut self, val: T) {
        let min_index = self.inner.last()
            // get last min value and its index
            .map(|(_, index)| (&self.inner[*index].0, index))
            // check if it is smaller then the current value
            .and_then(|(prev_min, min_index)| 
                (prev_min < &val).then(|| *min_index)
            )
            // if not smaller or does not exist
            // set it to the current index
            .unwrap_or(self.inner.len());

        self.inner.push((val, min_index));
    }
}
```

Here is a full implementation of the MinStack challenge [Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=9666695f0eaf437924c8976594a1583c).
Let me know if i should clarify something in the above code.

Docs for the used methods:

- [Vec::last](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.last)
- [bool::then](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.bool.html#method.then)
- [Option::map](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.map)
- [Option::and_then](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.and_then)
- [Option::unwrap_or](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.unwrap_or)